# Components won't show up when calling setVisible(true)

Tags: java, swing

Right now I cant figure out what is causing this problem.

I wrote a small(maybe silly!) dictionary program that loads a serialized hash map object(that has word-meaning pairs stored in it) and displays the meaning of the word entered by the user.

Initially i made it to load object completely and then display the GUI, but it took 3 secs to load the object, so i thought it would be better to show the gui and let the user type the word, meanwhile the object loads in a seperate thread, and if the user typed the word faster (i.e before the object is loaded) a dialog appears saying "loading.." and it closes when the object is loaded and user is shown the meaning.

The problem is - only the dialog box appears, the message -"loading..." doesnt appear ,as though it is tranparent....

Heres the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.io.*;

class Dict implements Runnable {

    HashMap hm = null;
    JTextField ji;
    JTextArea jo;
    JFrame jfobj;

    public void run() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("serialhm");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);// on an average it takes 3 secs to read the object, i made it sleep because the serialhm file i provided has only one word - "break"
            hm = (HashMap) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void print_meaning() {
        final JDialog dial = new JDialog();
        dial.setEnabled(true);
        dial.setModal(false);
        dial.setSize(200, 200);
        dial.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dial.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("loading......please wait"));
        dial.pack();
        if (hm == null) {

            dial.setVisible(true);//is not showing the message,only the dialog box is shown
            while (true) {
                if (hm != null) {
                    dial.setVisible(false);
                    dial.dispose();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        String word = ji.getText();
        String meaning = "";
        ArrayList al1 = (ArrayList) hm.get(word);
        if (al1 == null) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jfobj, "word unavailable");
            ji.setText("");
            jo.setText("");

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < al1.size(); i++) {
                meaning = meaning + "\n" + (String) al1.get(i);
            }

            jo.setText(meaning + "\n");
            ji.selectAll();
        }

    }

    public void gui() {
        jfobj = new JFrame();
        Font font1 = new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 17);

        jo = new JTextArea(15, 30);
        jo.setEditable(false);
        jo.setFont(font1);
        jo.setLineWrap(true);
        jo.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jo, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        ji = new JTextField(30);
        ji.setFont(font1);


        GridBagLayout gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
        Container contentPane = jfobj.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(gridBag);

        GridBagConstraints gridCons1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridCons1.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gridCons1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        contentPane.add(ji, gridCons1);

        GridBagConstraints gridCons2 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gridCons2.weightx = 1.0;
        gridCons2.weighty = 1.0;
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, gridCons2);

        ji.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                print_meaning();
            }
        });
        jfobj.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        jfobj.pack();
        jfobj.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Dict dobj = new Dict();
        Thread t = new Thread(dobj);
        t.start();
        dobj.gui();

    }
}
```

Here's the file('serialhm') that has the serialized hashmap object :
http://www.mediafire.com/?rc5nda0qs8891xv

For simplicity it amde it only a single worded hashmap and the only word in this dictionary is - "break"

Also, pardon my poor design.Thank you.

If anybody needs the full hashmap object serialized file, i'll upload it too,it has 203000 words.

Comment: That might not solve your issue but you should run all GUI related calls in the EDT (`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {public void run() {dobj.gui();}});`)

Comment: You should also introduce synchronization if you want to see hm becoming not null from your `print_meaning` method. You could make it volatile for example.

Comment: And finally you should not busy wait (`while(true)` in the EDT as it will hang your GUI until it exits the loop).

Comment: yeah, its right!!!. while(true) is responsible for this...i removed the while part and now its normal,except i am unable to setvisible(false) when the object is loaded....so how do i do it??

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is best solved by using SwingWorkers. You should have a look at the [Java Tutorial on Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: yeah..thanks, im giving it a look.swings are a lil bit complicated!!

Comment: Regarding Swing, once you make sure that any changes to GUI components are made in the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) AND you don't run long computation in the EDT, you have made a big step.

Comment: yeah i can see now after the while(true) devastation....atleast i now know whats the cause, im planning on moving the while(true) to a seperate thread

Answer (score 0):

ok, moved the `while(true)` block to a new thread and minor changes, now its fine, running exactly as i wanted.